# NoSuchMethodError when using assertThat+is with data type short

Tags: java, junit4, hamcrest

I have a class, with a `public short status`, and this line in a test:

```
assertThat(order.status, is(0));
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hamcrest.Matcher.describeMismatch(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/hamcrest/Description;)V

    at org.hamcrest.MatcherAssert.assertThat(MatcherAssert.java:18)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:956)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertThat(Assert.java:923)
    at com.example.OrderTest.testStuff(OrderTest.java:101)
    ...
```

However, if I do the following, which is uglier, the error goes away:

```
assertThat(order.status, is((short) 0));
```

What's up with that?

Comment: is your `order.status` of type short?

Comment: @Cargeh As stated in the very first line of the question, yes. 

Comment: @GhostCat But when there aren't any `short` literals in Java, shouldn't it work then? Shouldn't `is` go "ok, we have a `short` and an `int` here, and I know what to do with that"? Beyond that, the question is as minimal, complete and verifiable as it can be in my opinion...

Comment: As for the duplicate, that question does not answer my question. It answers why there are no short literals in Java. My question is why `assertThat` and `is` then cares about the difference between short and int, when there apparently isn't a difference to Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature of `assertThat()` is `assertThat(T actual, org.hamcrest.Matcher<T> matcher)`

T in your case is: **short**

So you need a `Matcher<Short>`. But 0 is an **int** literal. So you have to tell the compiler: use that int value as **short**.

Although it would be perfectly fine to turn 0-int into 0-short, Java isn't smart enough. As you are "restricting" something from the int range to short range, you have to put down that cast.

Comment: Java isn't smart enough... I'm always missing C# when working with Java 